# How do I retrieve a list of all children in a Firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The structure of my Firebase database is shown below. I want to make a list of all the Rooms in Android Studio. In other words, I need an array of [Room1, Room2, ...] for use in a spinner. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried so far.  There is documentation and lots of samples on how to query a node and iterate its children - this is a very common task.

Comment: Hey @MegBobo, do mark the answer as correct by clicking the tick mark button next to the answer and vote it up, this helps future readers of the question and I'd appreciate that too.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is loop over all the children of your database and add them to an `ArrayList` and then use an array adapter to display the list.

What I am saying, looks something like this in code:

```java
rootRef.child("Rooms").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            array.add(ds.child("Users").child("UserID").getValue(String.class));
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Do something for errors too
    }
});
```